# How do I access articles from the National Library of Medicine that have not been digitized?

Tags: data-request, usa, medical, government, research

I want to read a certain article in a scientific journal which I believe is stored at the National Library of Medicine, among other places. It does have a PMID. I looked at the instructions for obtaining a full article here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/guide/howto/obtain-full-text/ .

The particular article I want to access does not have a "Get full access" icon anywhere, and I can only view an abstract. I can thus only assume that the article is only stored in printed form at the NLM and has not been digitized. In fact, I have looked it up on Worldcat and was told that it is available at the NLM, plus some other libraries. I have also been unable to find any contact information of the publisher.

How can I, who am not affiliated with a university or any organization, obtain either a print copy of the article or get a digital copy? Is there a way to request a digitization? According to Worldcat, the nearest library containing the journal with the article I seek is rather far away. Is physically travelling to the location the only option?

The scientific journal in question is Eksperimentalna meditsina i morfologiia, volume 12.

Comment: What is the article you are seeking?

Comment: @Albert the name of the article which I am looking for translates as "[Changes in the bioelectrical activity of the stomach and duodenum in dogs with acute phosphoorganic compound poisoning before and after treatment with preparation H-5/T]" The original article is in Bulgarian.

Comment: i guess this is the abstract: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/4806515-changes-in-the-bioelectrical-activity-of-the-stomach-and-duodenum-in-dogs-with-acute-phosphoorganic-compound-poisoning-before-and-after-treatment-with-preparation-h-5t/#  unfortunately, following the pubmed download instructions doesn't work for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0Rk_zmMaWw